# When should I use 'side' in relation to a cube/cuboid?

Tags: idioms

Suppose I have a cube, and want to number each side from 1 to 6 in the following fashion: "number X corresponds to the [name of side] of the cube".

Is there any guide to whether I should use the word **side** in relation to the front/back/left/right/top/bottom of the cube?

Here is what I think:

- *Number 1 corresponds to the **front/front side** of the cube.* I am not sure which is more idiomatic.
- *Number 2 corresponds to the **back/back side** of the cube.* I am not sure which is more idiomatic.
- *Number 3 corresponds to the **right side** of the cube.* I think I should use "right side" rather than just "right".
- *Number 4 corresponds to the **left side** of the cube.* Same as "right side"
- *Number 5 corresponds to the **top / top side** of the cube.* I am not sure which is more idiomatic.
- *Number 6 corresponds to the **bottom / bottom side** of the cube.* I am not sure which is more idiomatic.

I am only talking about the outer surfaces of the cube. The correct answer should be applicable to rectangular cuboids as well.

---

Side note: It seems there's a little bit of misunderstanding. I'm not asking whether the more correct term to refer to the surface of a cube should be "side" or "face". I'm asking whether one should drop the word "side" in the case of the phrases above considering you would need to present all 6 phrases (in a presentation for example).

Comment: Are you asking if the word for the surface of a cube is *side*? Or are you asking what each directional side should be called? Also, as given in the answer of *faces*, it's obvious that there's more than one word that can be used for the surface. Similarly, you could say *rear* as opposed to *back*. Which particular aspect of the terminology are you concerned with, and what is the specific context? Colloquially and informally, most people use the word *side* if referring to the surface of a cube. Only in something more domain-specific would *face* be used; but it's correct in *that* context.

Comment: "asking what each direction side should be called" -> this would be correct. I'm not asking in a very mathematical degree context though. I guess it is more in a junior high school setting (or general or formal english setting).

Comment: I'm avoiding using rear. I'm more interested to see how should you use the word "back" in this context. "most people use the word side" -> that is what i'm still not quite sure about for these 4 terms (top, bottom, front, back). Does it sound redundant if I add the word "side" to these 4 terms when speaking in these pecific phrases for that specific topic? Are there any differences between BE and AE?

Comment: Deixis is involved. One can't top about the 'top' [face] of a cube, for instance, without somehow specifying orientation (as say in a diagram), as the cube can appear in 24 different equivalent orientations. Once orientation is specified, 'top' and 'bottom' are usually evident, as are 'front', 'back', 'left [face]' and 'right [face]'.

Comment: @Tomsofty33 If you just say you were *looking at the top of the cube* that would be sufficient and probably more common than you were *looking at the top **side** of the cube*. You can drop the noun that describes the surface (whatever word it is) and still be easily understood and idiomatic.

Comment: Yes but in the OP question, in the 6 phrases above, would you still choose to drop the "side" word ? (I mean for No.1, 2, 5 and 6) Would it still sound natural if dropped or is it actually more idiomatic to attach the "side" word in "these" particular phrases? (Again i'm referring to phrase 1,2, 5 and 6 above which are front / back side and top / bottom side, just to be clear, as I'm quite sure it wouldn't sound natural if you dropped the "side" word in phrase 3 and 4 above, cmiiw)

Comment: Also consider if you would have to present together all 6 phrases above (in a presentation for example) , would it still not look awkward if only phrases 3 & 4 has the word "side" and the others not?

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice for descriptions, use of terminology.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question. Please remember to be nice, everyone! I would most often omit 'side' for front/back, sometimes omit for top/bottom, and generally use 'side' with right/left.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't ask a question. I think you mean to ask what one would call these "sides": they are **faces**. As per Wolfram MathWorld:

- [**Face**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Face.html) the intersection of an n-dimensional [polytope](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polytope.html) with a tangent [hyperplane](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperplane.html).

It is common to refer to the front face, back face, left face, right face, top face, and bottom face of a cube.

Comment: It is common in? BE or AE? Both?

Comment: I didn't ask "a" question. I asked 4 questions. Point number 1,2, 5 and 6.

Comment: As I said in the comments above, the word face would be too mathematical in this context. I'm searching for how should it be in a more general / formal setting.

Comment: @Tomsofty33 — If you asked four questions, that’s three too many for SE. Be grateful for a clear concise answer. Your question(s) is/are on the way to being ruled off-topic.

Comment: @David OP is asking for what style should be applied. I don't think 4 separate questions are necessary.